# Attach DataURL canvas image as file attachment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

Hi I need some help getting webcamjs.js to work with Contact Forms 7 or on WordPress in general. I can call webcamjs to a WordPress page, I have the js library enqueued to the page and it works fine. The image captures to data_uri and is displayed on a page in a div.
But I’m struggling to convert the canvas into a file attachment for use in Contact Form 7.
I have managed to insert the undecoded img into a text field as labelled here as ‘webcam’. I can send the form with the encoded base64 string, but I need to be able to send it as a viewable picture.

I assume I need to convert this to a blob and somehow attach that to a file input field in CF7. I don’t know what approach to take here.

```
<script >
    function take_snapshot() {
        // take snapshot and get image data
        Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
            // display results in page
            var raw_image_data = data_uri.replace(/^data\:image\/\w+\;base64\,/, '');
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' +
                '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
    // attach resulting base64 string to text input form field webcam
            document.getElementById('webcam').value = raw_image_data;
        });
    } </script>
```